# Swift getting image from Parse.com and setting image with it

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Trying to get an image from parse and set a uiimage with it but keep getting this error. Running Xcode 7 and swift 2.0

Cannot invoke 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(imageData:NSData,error:NSError.Type,()->())'

```
let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Items")
    query.whereKey("ItemOwner", equalTo: "Shreddish")

    // 3
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Successfully retrieved: \(objects)")
            for object in objects! {
                print(object)
                let imageFile: PFFile = object["ItemMainImage"] as! PFFile
                var image = imageFile.getData()

                imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(imageData: NSData, error: NSError) {


                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the signature of `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`?

Comment: @NobodyNada sounds like a function that takes a Closure

Comment: yea I tried following some other example code but it didn't work, @NobodyNada just figured it out, I matched the signature of findObjectsInBackground and it worked

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Yes, but we need to know what kind of closure.

Comment: @NobodyNada the input parameters for it are: nserror and nsdictionary, and it returns void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(imageData: NSData, error: NSError) {
    ...
}
```

To

```
imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    ...
}
```